# PlayOnLinux audio issues

Tags: sound, wine, pulseaudio, alsa, playonlinux

I am running Ubuntu 16.04, and I have a problem with PlayOnLinux. Whenever I try to start a game through POL, it seems to kill the system's sound. Even after POL is closed, none of the sound outputs work. Changing from HDMI audio to analog doesn't change anything. One thing to note is that the WINE install uses the ALSA driver while the system uses PulseAudio. What could be causing this issue? Thanks!

Update: Tested the issue further by launching Skyrim and using Spotify to test when the sound goes out. Turns out the problem starts when Steam starts through POL. Also tried running the debugger on Skyrim and got this curious ALSA error:

ALSA lib pcm.c:7963:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default

Logfile: http://pastebin.com/PQfVfXJ4

Comment: Version of POL?

Comment: POL version is 4.2.10, WINE version is 1.7.36.