# PulseAudio/ALSA issue in 'PCSX2', error reads: ALSA lib pcm.c:8306:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, pcsx2

I've been trying to get PCSX2 to work (PS2 emulator) and when I load an ISO it crashes giving out the error in the title.

This is the same issue as described in the following links, well at least the same error output:

[PlayOnLinux audio issues](https://askubuntu.com/questions/809791/playonlinux-audio-issues)

https://thehumble.ninja/2014/02/06/fixing-alsa-lib-pcmc7843snd_pcm_recover-underrun-occurred-while-keeping-pulseaudio-in-your-system/

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=185736

I suppose my question is; how can I apply these fixes to Ubuntu 18.04?

I think I am supposed to edit a configuration file for pulseaudio to increase the buffer size, but I can only find the examples for other distros.